# Probability of geometric brownian motion taking a certain value

Tags: brownian-motion

So we have an asset whose price follows a GMB:

$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t d W_t$

and want to know the probability that it drops 5% or more at time $t = 2$, given that $\mu = 0.04$ and $\sigma = 0.2$. I think [(thanks Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) that it should be solved like this:

- first pass is finding the value of $S_2$ (question: how do I compute $W_t$?)
- somehow taking advantage that $S_t$ is log-normally distributed (I'm not sure how to use standard normal CDF tables)

Disclaimer: I know this must be super simple, but have not found the solution and don't know anyone that can help.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'drops 5% or more at time t=2'. GBM is continuous. Drops 5% or more in what time period?

Comment: I have to translate the statement from Italian, however I think we are not interested in any value *before* $t = 2$, nor in any value *after*; just exactly at $t = 2$

Comment: OK, so let's say the process starts at $S_0$ and we require $S_2 \le 0.95 S_0$. What is the probability distribution of $S_2$?

Comment: If I'm supposed to know, I'm afraid I don't. There's nothing more in the original problem statement

Comment: **Can't understand the downvotes, plus it's just stupid to not tell what's wrong with my question because I can't guess how to improve neither this very question nor my attitude.**

Comment: Your Wikipedia link has all the information you'll need.

Comment: @Raffaele It sounds like you're trying to skip ahead of your comfort level. I understand your frustration; after realizing I didn't understand SDEs or the notation, I had to go back to the basics of set theory, probability theory, calculus, measure theory, random processes, and ultimately stochastic integration. I am afraid that in order to really understand this stuff, it is not possible to skip any of those steps.

Comment: @David thanks for the advice. It's not easy to learn these things by oneself, and it requires quite some time given my level. Do you have any advice to shorten the learning path, like an author beginner-friendly that's still rigorous so that once I become confident in the notation and the jargon I can keep on going by myself?

Comment: @Raffaele Not really. If you want to get a more holistic understanding of stochastic processes without getting deep into the math, I think that the following Wikipedia entries (in this order) would help: set theory; probability space; Measure (mathematics); Expected value; Conditional expectation; Normal distribution; Stochastic process; Wiener process; Brownian motion; and Geometric Brownian Motion.The missing link in all of this is how to get GBM from standard BM, which canonically requires Itô's lemma (hard). However, it is possible to intuit this result from Jensen's inequality (easy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the solution of this SDE is,

$$S_t = S_0e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t+\sigma W_t},$$

which is equal in law to:

$$S_t = S_0e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t+\sigma \sqrt{t}Z},$$

where $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. You have:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{S_2}{S_0}-1\leq-0.05\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(Z \leq \frac{\log(0.95)- 2\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2} \sigma}\right),$$

quantity that you can calculate given the table of the normal law.

Comment: Up and thanks for stopping by! Would you mind explaining why $\sigma W_t$ becomes $\sigma \sqrt{t} Z$ and especially the last transformation?

Comment: Because $W_t$ is Brownian Motion. You need to refresh your memory on BM, GBM, etc.

Comment: It sounded like @Raffaele wanted the first time hitting model (I.e, what he meant by first pass). Can you confirm that this is not the case? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-hitting-time_model

Comment: Confirm that is **not** the case. This answer is the solution to my problem, even if I'm still struggling to understand how to get there

Comment: You will need basic notions in stochastic calculus to understand how to compute the solution of such SDEs, it is explained here by the way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Geometric_Brownian_motion

Secondly, by definition of the BM, $W_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$, and you know that, if $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then $\mu+\sigma Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, hence $\sqrt{t}Z\overset{\mathcal{L}}{=} W_t$.

For the last equality, it's just that, for $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, you have $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq a)=\mathbb{P}\left(Z\leq \frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$.